# Why does the drive report full?

Tags: windows-8.1, disk-space

A computer shows often in the morning en error telling that the hard disk ran out of space, but in reality the disk is less than half full. It is a SDD disk.

In Window Explorer, the disk displays this message :

> 0 bytes free C:
>   NTFS

After a restart, all becomes normal again.

What could be the problem ?
What steps to take to troubleshoot ?

Comment: You may backup your important data. Sounds like your disk may fail.

Comment: What does it look like within drive management? Also please comb the event logs and look for hard disk related warnings or errors. Also backup your data asap in case it does lead to a HDD failure.

Comment: Why not use [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) to see what’s going on...

Comment: What is the total capacity of the disk, and how old is the disk? And what brand/type/model is it? (Right-click drive in explorer, go to properties, then to tab "hardware", it should list your drive model(s) there.) If it's a smaller disk (say max 64 GB), it may just be some temporary folder or file growing more than expected. For instance temp files for windows-, antivirus-, office-, steam-games- or whoknowswhat-updates, combined with a dynamically resized pagefile. Or something like that.